# Cannot update DocuSign top-level Account User information?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am staring at the DocuSign REST API Guide and I see no request to update, say, User LastName. It looks like DocuSign may regard this top-level information as immutable for security/identity purposes. These are the PUT operations I am seeing related to users:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/custom_settings 
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/profile/image 
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/settings 
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureIdOrName} 
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureIdOrName}/initials_image 
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureIdOrName}/signature_image 
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/social
```

Yes, it looks like `/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/settings` is what I am looking for but this request covers only `userSettings`, `signerEmailNotifications` and `senderEmailNotifications`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the functionality in DocuSign is not exposed to public API for security reasons.  We don't want people to change people's identity for example.  So not every single setting is going to have a full CRUD operation set.

Maybe it would be helpful to hear what you are looking to accomplish?  Here is the list of common integration scenarios: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes  - it might help.